# Change option when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a reservation form. In case if one of my customers fall into a problem, I want them to call me in a time that they prefer. For that, I have created two drop down list boxes. First combo box should contain two options (as given in the snippet) with **Call today** selected by default. If second option **Call Tomorrow** is chosen, the second drop-down list should be filled with the available time slots like:

```
12:00
13:00
16:00
20:00
...
...
```

and so forth. How could this be achieved?

```js
  
  $("#call-day").change(function(e){
    val=$("option:selected",this).val();
    if(val=="today"){
      
    }else if(val=="tomorrow"){
      
    }
  });
```

```html
<select name="call-day" id="when-ajax">
  <option class="today">Call Today</option>
  <option class="tomorrow">Call Tomorrow</option>
</select>

<select name="hours">
  <option>Call Now</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: thanks @Difster my english so bad after jquery I'm thinking improve my english if I could.my question is chancing select option according to my select

Comment: . it was like that what I want but I did it finally thanks
http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/dWPRJP

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so vague. Please reword it. From what I understood out of your description, following should help you to achieve what you are trying to. Note that I took the liberty to assume certain facts.

```js
  
  $("select[name='call-day']").change(function(e){
    val=$(this).val();
    if(val=="today"){
      //What you want to do here is not mentioned. So I am leaving it blank
    }else if(val=="tomorrow"){
      //Available time slots should be retrieved from some persistent location. Assuming it is already done...
      var availableSlots = ["12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "16:00"];
      $("select[name='hours']").empty();
      $("select[name='hours']").append("<option value=''>--Select Time--</option");
      for(i in availableSlots){
        var item = availableSlots[i];
        var optionElement = "<option value='"+ item +"'>" + item + "</option>";
        $("select[name='hours']").append(optionElement);
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<select name="call-day" id="when-ajax">
  <option value="today">Call Today</option>
  <option value="tomorrow">Call Tomorrow</option>
</select>

<select name="hours">
  <option>Call Now</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```